How to simplify these clauses into implications for an implication graph?
For a uni project I have to create an implication graph from clauses.
For example, from the clause (a or b), I can determine these implication :

¬a -> b
¬b -> a

but I really can't find the right implications to add from this clause :
(a and b) or (¬a and b)
any way to simplify it so that I can determine the right implications ?
Tried to translate the "and" clauses into "or" clauses but didn't work..

Apply De Morgan's laws

I'm not really sure what this question is asking.  The obvious inference is that "b" is true and you nothing whatsoever about "a".  Or in logic: b.

As commented by @Mad Physicist, you could use De Morgan's theorem to translate the expression into Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF).
(a and b) or (~a and b) = ~(~(a and b) and ~(~a and b))
                        = ~((~a or ~b) and {a and ~b))
                        = ~((~a and ~b) or (a and ~b) or ~b)
                        = ~(~a and ~b) and ~(a and ~b) and b
                        = (a or b) and (~a or b) and b
                        = b

For larger expressions, Tseytin Transformation is a commonly used way to keep intermediate expressions small:
The original expression is broken down into subexpressions:
F := (a and b) or (not a and b)

is tranformed into
F := x or y
x := a and b
y := ~a and b

Each of the subexpressions is translated into a set of CNF clauses:
(~x or F) 
(~y or F)
(x or y or ~F)

(a or ~x)
(b or ~x)
(~a or ~b or x)

(~a or ~y)
(b or ~y)
(a or ~b or y)

Output F is asserted to true. This leads to:
(x or y)

(a or ~x)
(b or ~x)
(~a or ~b or x)

(~a or ~y)
(b or ~y)
(a or ~b or y)

This form should enable you to derive the implications.
